# Keep focus after selection is made Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm having an issue with Select2 keeping focus after a selection is made. I have some long forms in my application that need to be tabbed through. Right now, once a selection is made with Select2, focus is lost and so it's not possible to tab to the next field.

You can test this on their examples page. The standard select field allows tabbing after the selection is made, the Select2 field does now.

Edit: Example of an area where I use Select2.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Addresses[i].City)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Addresses[i].City, new { @class = "form-control jsAddressCity" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Addresses[i].City)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Addresses[i].StateId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Addresses[i].StateId, new SelectList(Model.StatesList, "Id", "Code", Model.Addresses[i].StateId), "Select State", new { @class = "form-control jsAddressStateId jsSelect2" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Addresses[i].StateId)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Addresses[i].Zip)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Addresses[i].Zip, new { @class = "form-control jsAddressZip" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Addresses[i].Zip)
</div>
```

JS:

```
        $(".jsSelect2").select2({
            width: "100%",
            theme: 'bootstrap'
        });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/1183/ I had made a fiddle i cant able to figure out your issue. can you pls give details

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's going on with mine. In your example it works fine. If you select an item using tab or select, your Select2 closes but stays focused, allowing you to tab into the next control. On mine, when you make your selection, Select2 closes but focus is no longer on the control. There is no focus, so you can't tab to what's next. I have the latest update of Select2 and I don't believe I'm doing anything differently other than using the Bootstrap theme. It does the same thing with or without that theme.

Comment: Pls provide your html

Comment: Edited my post with a brief example of it being used.

Comment: can you pls verify which version of select2 you are using

Comment: can you pls try this  $(".jsSelect2")..select2({
  width: "100%",
  theme: 'bootstrap',
  closeOnSelect: true
});  if this is working i can add it as an answer it i think there is a bug in old versions so that every one will get informed

Comment: That didn't work for me unfortunately. I'm on version 4.0.3 which appears to be the most recent version. I did download this using NuGet, so I'm not sure if there's any reason it would be better to instead just download from github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. It's a bug in version 4.0.3, Use select2 4.0.2 instead

Comment: I went to 4.0.2 instead and still came across that issue. But the workaround in the link there fixed it for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: We went back from 4.0.5 to 4.0.2 and this solved for us the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using 4.0.13, the issue is still not fixed

Answer (score 3):

To keep the select2 focused and open after selecting an option, we just need to provide an additional parameter while loading it.

```
$(".jsSelect2").select2({
        width: "100%",
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        closeOnSelect: false
    });
```

Hope this will help someone in the future.